# Jquery Slicebox throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting following error with jquery slice box

```
TypeError: $ is undefined

var $event = $.event,
```

around here in slicebox.js

```
( function( $, window, undefined ) {// start of the file and getting error as soon as it calls 1st event
'use strict';

var $event = $.event,// getting error here
$special,
resizeTimeout;
```

I am using jquery 1.7.0 if it is causing error then please do let me know.

Comment: Did you try other versions of jQuery? Do you happen to use noConflict()?

Comment: make sure jQuery is at top of page, befor slicebox library.

Comment: Also, codrops is using 1.8.2, you could try that one. And also like @ZaheerAhmed mentions, check if you load your jQuery before Slicebox.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar, Zaheer let me test this.

Comment: What's the last line of your file triggering the IIFE? Is jQuery passed as the first argument?